# how to correctly write ajax pagination code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem to solve for coders and AJAX lovers.
I have examples of code javascript, jquery, and php.

```
  function find_page_number( element ) {
    element.find('span').remove();
        return parseInt( element.html() );
    }

    $(document).on( 'click', '#PaginationExample a', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        page = find_page_number( $(this).clone() );
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        action: 'ajax_pagination',
        query_vars: ajaxpagination.query_vars,
        page: page
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#showcase').find( 'article' ).remove();
        $('#showcase nav').remove();
        $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#showcase').append( '<div class="page-content" id="loader">Loading New Posts...</div>' );
    },
    success: function(html ) {
        $('#showcase').empty();
        $('#showcase').append(html );
        },

        })
    })
})(jQuery);
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_pagination', 'ajax_pagination' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_pagination', 'ajax_pagination' );

function ajax_pagination() {
$query_vars = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query_vars'] ), true );

    $query_vars['paged'] = $_POST['page'];


    $posts = new WP_Query( $query_vars );
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $posts;

    add_filter( 'editor_max_image_size', 'my_image_size_override' );

    if( ! $posts->have_posts() ) { 
        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
    }
    else {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) { 
            $posts->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        }
    }
    remove_filter( 'editor_max_image_size', 'my_image_size_override' );

    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'webisawesome' ),
        'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'webisawesome' ),
        'before_page_number' => '<ul id="PaginationExample">' . __( 'Page', 'webisawesome' ) . ' </ul>',
    ) );

    wp_die();
}

function my_image_size_override() {
    return array( 825, 510 );
}


function add_myjavascript(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-pagination', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/ajax-pagination.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true  );
 global $wp_query;
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-pagination', 'ajaxpagination', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'query_vars' => json_encode( $wp_query->query )
));

  }
  add_action( 'init', 'add_myjavascript' );
```

html part

```
<nav>   <ul id='PaginationExample' style=" display:flex;
  justify-content:center;">
 <li><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Back ') ?></li>||
 <li><?php next_posts_link('Forward &raquo;') ?></li>
  </ul></nav>
```

So who can answer why it returns to 0 after clicking pages? Does anybody know what can be wrong and what is missing to make the code to work properly and page posts?  My website is https://www.webisawesome.com/category/services WordPress based:) Let me know if you need more information about it. Thanks to all!

Comment: Couldn't see such pagination as mention is the page that you have provided. Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: right, I deactivated a code, commented out

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are actually trying to achieve? At the moment looking at the website, it is empty and can't really gauge what the issue is.

Comment: alright,  Thank you for your time! I am activating the code. (Only for this page) So everybody can test it. Just try to navigate posts forward and back.

Comment: unfortunately, nobody gave a solution so I am going to close this question.